# How to get HT12D to default state?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have made following project using a [Holtek HT-12D decoder](http://www.holtek.com/pdf/consumer/2_12dv120.pdf):

[image: Holtek Transmitter / Receiver Project]

My problem is that when I press any switch on the transmitter and cut power to the transmitter by holding push switch, the receiver end is still showing a LED output. I want it to go to the default state of all LEDs off whenever transmitter goes out of range or power to it is cut.

Comment: If I press my car lock/unlock transmitter to unlock the doors, the doors unlock. If I remove the battery from the transmitter, the doors remain unlocked. This doesn't surprise me. Can you provide a link to the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

When data is being transmitted continously the `VT` line will stay high while valid data is being received. I was going to suggest using a transistor connected to the high-side of the LEDs but looking at the HT-12D datasheet the sink / source current for each pin is shown as 1.6mA typical. They don't show a maximum so maybe it has current limiting, but some further buffering of the data lines is probably in order.

A typical [7400 quad NAND gate](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf) normally has a drive of 16-20mA (check the datasheet for the particular part you choose) and should be a suitable choice. As you want the LEDs to be on when the data outputs are low you'll also need inverters such as a 7404 on the data lines:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbN0Y1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are quite a few ways you could go about it, I've just shown an example using basic logic gates that are easy to source and to understand. You could also use a microcontroller if you're familiar with programming them and you could even replace the whole HT-12D with one if you decoded the protocol.

Another thing to note is that when I've used the Holtek chips in the past sometimes the `VT` line will 'flicker' because of poor communications on occasions. If that's a problem with your application you'll need a way to introduce a delay into `VT` going low, maybe a simple diode and RC arrangement would do the job but see how this goes for a start.